# problems with including a custom login page in cordova when using angular cli in the same project

Tags: cordova, azure, angular, angular-cli, adal

I have a cordova project with several bundle.js files from my angular cli project.  I have the app selector and the bundle.js files in the body tag in index.html in the cordova project. I'm going to create a new login page in the cordova project so it will be possible to login with Azure. My question is, how will I be able to add another page to the body tag in index.html that is going to be loaded before the selector? I cannot replace the selector because it only gives me error "The selector "ipool-app" did not match any elements".

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<base href=".">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" />
</head>
<body>
<app>
<div class="center-div center-text">
Loading... <br /><br />
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw"></i>
</div>
</app>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have understood you very clearly, but commonly in Cordova project, we can simply create `html` files in our project, as new pages in application. E.G. you can create a html page for login operation, save the authentication token or the signed users' info in the `sessionStorage`, which can be shared in different pages.

Otherwise, you can leverage Azure Mobile Apps to implement login operation with AAD or other IDPs within Mobile Apps client SDK, in this case you dont have to create an additional login page.

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthahow-to-authenticate-users for more details about how to authenticate users via AAD in Cordova.

Comment: Yes, but how do I change which page that will be my startup page? And how do I do with the selector "app" that comes from the angular project? If I removes it from the body tag in index.html it will not be able to run the "app"

Comment: I still cannot understand you clearly why you need to change startup page. As you are using Angular, so you are recommended to think about SPA, you can create angular templates instead of new pages, and use Angular's router to handle page shifts. If you consist to use new html pages, you need to include all the dependency js files in each html page, and also bootstrap angular application in each html page.

Comment: I use the ADAL for Cordova plugin for authentication functionality when the user is logging in with azure. If I create a login page in the angular project, how do I pass the information forth and back between the angular and cordova project? Lets say that I create a login page in the cordova project, then I don't need to pass information to the adal plugin index.js file when the user clicks on login. Which alternative do you think is the easiest and how do I pass data between the two projects?

Comment: You can use the [HTML5 Local Storage feature](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), e.g. (`localStorage`,`sessionStorage`) to save the data in phone and share in different pages.